# ESP8266 Captive Portal and jump to "normal" Browser

Tags: html, esp8266, arduino-ide, captiveportal, esp8266wifi

I like to run some esp8288 with some custemizing or controles in AP mode.
To make it easyer to use I like to use the captive portal function to make the access easyer for the user.
So the after connecting the captive portal will pop up e.g. on Iphone and it shows only one link like "open on Browser".

I already learnd that the portal app is only let you use a link to e.g. safari if the server sends a webpage like:

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Success</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>Success</BODY></HTML>
```

but I was not able to find a way how this is possible.

Does somebody already managed that on a ESP8266. I already tryed to analyse pages from T-Online or vodafone where this is possible, but without an result.

Jens

Comment: the WiFiManager library does it

Answer (score -1):

The WiFiManager library, surtenly, does not provide such an option to open full (not mini) browser, but just to save WiFi credentials and turn WiFi STAtion mode.
Would be nice to see the WireShark sniff of the T-Online and/or Vodafone captive logins to see how they done.
Actually the `<TITLE>Success</TITLE>` response You mention, tells the mini-browser its already the Internet connection (not captive portal) and it can close

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: In the next days I will try to use my Laptop to analyse the network trafic. I already saw on the vodafone the folowing page asked to open in Safari after I was connected to the internet <a style="color: #fff" href="http://www.vodafone.de/impressum.html">Impressum</a> . Is there an app like the F12 function in Firefox for IOS.